# How to make TensorBoard show variable names in the graph?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I was following [an intro to the TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started) and noticed that all graph visualizations there have node names which are same as the corresponding variables' names. But when I tried to generate the same visualizations, TensorBoard just used the type of operations as names.

For example, following code is the same as in the intro

```py
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.Session()

a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
adder_node = a + b
add_and_triple = adder_node * 3.

tf.summary.FileWriter("D:\\TF", sess.graph)

print(sess.run(add_and_triple, {a: 3, b: 4.5}))
```

When I visualize the graph using TensorBoard is give me following

[image: TensorBoard result]

while in the intro it was like this

[image]

I've found the way to manually set the names - using the `name` parameter like this

```py
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name = 'a')
```

But this seems to be a lot of work and ruins all the beauty of

```py
adder_node = a + b
```

Is there any setting to make it automatically?

Answer (score 0):

For **tf.Placeholders**, **tf.Variables**, and **tf.Constants** you can use argument **name** to assign a name to those nodes in tensorflow. Those names will be used by TensorBoard when plotting the graph.

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="x")
y= tf.valiable(0.5, tf.float32, name="y")
z= tf.constant(1.0, tf.float32, name="z")
```

I do not think there be an automatic way to assign the variable names in your code to those placeholders and variables in a computation graph.